# Error in ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, html, sql, ado.net

There seems to be a problem with my code. It appears there is something wrong with my .ExecuteNonQuery. The error I am receiving is
"No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type." 
Could anyone see what is wrong with what I'm doing? Thanks a lot

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class CustomerLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
static readonly string scriptErrorUserId =
 "<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
 "alert (\"Error - UserId you keyed in is taken up, please key in another UserId\");\n" +
 "</script>";

static readonly string scriptSuccessNewAccount =
"<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
"alert (\"Your account has been succesfully created - Thank You!\");\n" +
"</script>";

static readonly string scriptErrorInput =
"<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
"alert (\"Error - Please fill up all the textboxes\");\n" +
"</script>";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}



protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-UNIV3GV;Initial Catalog=Bolsen;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
    sqlCon.Open();
    Type csType = this.GetType();
    //Check to ensure that UserId keyed in is not being in used by other Customers     

    SqlCommand sqlcmd;
    SqlDataReader rdr;
    string strSQLSelect = "SELECT cEmail FROM Customers ";
    sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(strSQLSelect, sqlCon);
    //SqlDataReader reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
    rdr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read() == true)


        if (txtEmail.Text == (string)rdr["cEmail"])
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Error", scriptErrorUserId);
            sqlCon.Close();
            return;
        }
    if (txtEmail.Text == "")
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Error", scriptErrorInput);
        sqlCon.Close();
        return;
    }
    // insert new record
    string strSQLInsert = "INSERT INTO "
        + " Customer  (Firstname, Lastname, cNumber, cCompanyName, cCompanyAddress, cEmail, cPassword)"
        + " VALUES (@FN, @LN, @Num, @CName, @CAdd, @Email, @PW)";
    sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(strSQLInsert, sqlCon);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CFN", txtFN.Text);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", txtLN.Text);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num", txtNum.Text);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CName", txtCN);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAdd", txtCA.Text);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PW", txtPwd.Text);
    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlCon.Close();


    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Success", scriptSuccessNewAccount);

    // prepare Session variables for newly registered customer

}
```

}

Comment: It's not your problem (as pointed out by TheGeneral) but you should get out of the habit of using `AddWithValue`, it has quirks which can end up biting you. It's preferable to use (for example) `sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, FieldLength).Value = YourValue;`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this was taught to me by my school but in all honesty I think they're lacking behind.

Answer (score 2):

Simple missing Property `Text`

Essentially, it doesn't know how to convert a `TextBox` (object), to your *Sql* parameter

Replace

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CName", txtCN);
```

With

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CName", txtCN.Text);
```